# How to not save same email users in Node.js?

Tags: express, mongoose

I want to register users but with no same email.

If email already exists,they cannot register.

Since my email field is an array,I am confused how to approach this.

<-- Here is the model -->

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
  },
  emailInfo: [
    {
      email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
      },
      emailType: String,
    },
  ],

  password: {
    type: String,
  },
```

<-- Here is the controller -->

```
registerNewUser: async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { firstname, lastname, emailInfo, password} = req.body;
    try {
         let user = await User.findOne({ email: emailInfo.email });

       if (user) {
       return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This email id is already in use" });
      }
       user = new User({
        firstname,
        lastname,
        emailInfo,
        password,
      });
      const { emailType, email } = req.body;
      const emailList = { emailType, email };
      user.emailInfo.unshift(emailList);
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      await user.save()
}
```

I am getting an error "Cannot read property of 'email' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested search condition:

```js
let user = await User.findOne({ 'emailInfo.email': emailInfo.email });
```